# minimal surfaces explanation

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

"I was reading the book 'DIFFERENTIAL GEOMETRY OF CURVES & SURFACES,' and I don't understand where the parametrization of the surface comes from.
$$
\frac{\partial x^{\tau}}{\partial u} = xu + thN_{u} + th_uN,
$$

$$
\frac{\partial x^{\tau}}{\partial v} = xv + thN_{v} + th_vN.
$$

"[image]

Comment: I don't have Do Carmo in front of me, but it looks to me like he is saying to take any regular surface, and then to perturb the surface a little bit, using the function $h$. He says that if I push the surface by $t < \epsilon$, I get a new parametrization, given by that formula. Looks like just normal calculus to obtain that result by differentiating the formula he gives for $\varphi$.

Comment: I do not follow your question. The parametrization is given above (the formula $\varphi(u,v,t) = \dots$). These are merely the partial derivatives of that function.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don´t undertand how they get $x_{v}+thN-{v}+th_{v}N$  in  the parametrization

Comment: That is not the parametrization. Please read what I said and respond to it.